# PyPlot reverse y-axis and logarithmic

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to both reverse the y-axis with `PyPlot` and make it logarithmic? I know that one of the two options can be done with

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

and

```
plt.yscale('log')
```

However, the combination does not work. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What order did you try them in?  [This thread](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/missing-ticks-on-inverted-log-axis-td41063.html) suggests you need to set the scale first and then invert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this is simply to use this in the following order:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've tried that and had no effect in case of multiple plots on the same figure.

Comment: This is this simplistic version, I'm sure there is an equivalent for axes.